# Microsoft Azure sql data warehouse supported in Informatica

Tags: sql-server, azure, informatica, azure-synapse

I want to do simple transformation with source as Flat file and target as SQL Data Warehouse.In target Analyser using ODBC Connection I am able to connect the SQL Data Warehouse and connection is successful,but no tables are listed and I am unable to select a table to import.(Sample Tables are created in SQL Data warehouse)
Whether it is possible to create a Source/target as SQL Data warehouse?If so kindly help me to solve the issue.

Thanks & Regards
Prakash

Comment: At a glance, this looks as if you'd lack some priviliges and thus cannot see the tables. Are you on the right schema?

Answer (score 2):

Informatica does offer support for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and are listed as a Partner solution https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-integrate-solution-partners/

Here is a link to all the configuration required for Informatica Cloud for example: https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/5/IC_Winter2016_MicrosoftAzureSQLDataWarehouseConnectorGuide_en.pdf

What version are you using Prakash?

If you are trying to select data from SQLDW I would also check that your connection is targeting the specific database you have created. You could be connecting to the master db on the logical server rather than the sqldw database itself.

Comment: I am using Informatica Power Center Client 9.6.1.I want to know whether SQL Azure will be supported in Informatica or we require Informatica Cloud.

Comment: Make sure you are using 9.6.1 HF4. Then you can leverage PolyBase functionality with Azure SQL Data Warehouse.